# DVD ROM is not working

Tags: linux, boot, compact-disc

I have a DVD RW drive that is well listed in the bios, and if no CD is in, it is also present in the "My Computer" of my Fedora 16.

But when I put a disc on it, the icon disapear from "My Computer", and I can not do anything with this ! (Like erasing a RW disc).

I'd like to boot a Fedora 17 Live CD image. I burned it on an other computer but when I try to run it in bios, nothing is done and I'm redirected to Grub of my HD.

The command `cdrecord -scanbus` shows this :

```
wodim: Warning: controller returns wrong size for CD capabilities page.
wodim: Cannot get CD capabilities data.
    6,1,0   601) 'HD-DT%ST' 'DVD%RAM G@22NP20' '1&04' Removable CD-ROM
```

And when I try to mount manually the disc, I got this error :

```
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock
```

Here's a paste of `dmesg | grep sr0` :

```
[    5.161265] sr0: scsi-1 drive
[    5.161621] sr 6:0:1:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  834.545978] sr0: Hmm, seems the drive doesn't support multisession CD's
[  841.731194] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Get configuration 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[  842.021640] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  842.021652] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[  842.021662] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  842.021672] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[  842.021688] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[  842.021697] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
[  842.023715] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  843.048203] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[  843.048211] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  843.048219] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[  843.048234] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[  843.048274] EXT4-fs (sr0): unable to read superblock
[  843.063155] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Get configuration 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[  843.075904] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Get configuration 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[  843.220512] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  843.220522] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[  843.220530] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  843.220538] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[  843.220553] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[  843.220609] FAT-fs (sr0): unable to read boot sector
```

The lines from `Sense Key ..` (line 6) to `DRIVER_SENSE` (line 11) are repeating a lot.

I then changed my DVD player with an other spare one I had, and the disc didn't boot neither.
I then changed the IDE cable, but still no success.

I tried a driver CD from Logitech to see if it was working, here's the dmesg log :

```
[91262.960539] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xdread, Read track info 52 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 20 00
[91262.960561] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[91262.960570] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
```

I then tried with an old game CD (for windows), here's the result :

```
[91372.015116] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xdread, Read track info 52 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 20 00
[91372.015138] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[91372.015147] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
```

(same error)

If I try to mount it (linux : mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom/), here's what dmesg says :

```
[94083.825753] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 01 00
[94083.825769] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 64
[94083.825815] isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=sr0, iso_blknum=16, block=16
[94083.840266] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Get configuration 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[94083.840286] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[94083.840293] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[94083.867380] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[94083.867390] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[94083.867399] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[94083.867407] sr 6:0:1:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[94083.867423] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[94083.867466] FAT-fs (sr0): unable to read boot sector
```

My driver is a LG GH22NP20BB.

**Update 1** :

I tried again with an other DVD driver, here's the dmesg :

```
[  343.828326] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xdread, Read track info 52 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 20 00
[  343.828349] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  343.828357] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
```

Oh well, same error! So it's related to the mother board (that's all I can guess)

Could it be a wrong configured bios? (like sata/ide/raid something?)

**Update 2**:

I resetted my bios, and it didn't changed anything, so I think the problem is on the motherboard. I'll see with my manufacturer.

What can I do to make it work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you run the command `dmesg` in a shell and show the lines where `sr0` is detected and classified?

Comment: No problem, I updated my question regarding it :)

Comment: Are the error messages the same for both drives? Maybe they are too old for the DVD, Does a "normal" CD work?

Comment: No, neither, I first burned the Fedora 17 iso on a CD-R, without any successes :/

Comment: Have you tried an original, not a CD-R?

Comment: I tried something else, I put the Fedora 17 disc on an other computer, and it did start, so the disc is working, but not on my computer.

Comment: Have you tried using a different IDE connector on your motherboard?

Comment: I have only one IDE connector :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like the problem is located on the mainboard the controller might be broken, so there is probably not much you can do. One last thing you could check is to see if there is something behind the connector on the mainboard that could cause shorts. Sometimes there are excessive brass spacers, that were not removed before the board was put in. In cases with poor quality the board carrier might also be bent so the board is touching it directly. Since even the drives's name does not come up correctly, it could also be some pin not being connected properly. So also make sure that no pins in the connector are bent and thus left unconnected.  If the connector is dirty, some rubbing alcohol might help.

If there are no such problems (or there was one but removing it does not fix your problem) you have three options to keep the otherwise working board.

- use a drive with another connector like S-ATA or maybe USB (assuming such conector is available)
- use a ATA/S-ATA bridge to connect your drive to a S-ATA port on your mainboard (assuming there is one)
- use a separate ATA adapter on a PCI card (assuming there is an available PCI slot)

While the first option might be the most expensive, I would recommend it because it will just work. Using separate bridges or adapter cards might cause new trouble like not being able to boot or not supporting ATAPI devices.

Comment: I think it's the most complete answer, thus winning the bounty+accepted. I don't think I will have an exact magical answer that will resolve my problem. I'll try your suggestions and see what's happening! Oddest thing : My drive works at first boot (when my computer was off some hours), but after a moment, its stop working ...

Comment: Interesting point, this is likely related to thermal expansion while the computer is getting warm. If your cable sits firmly in the connector this might indicate a bad solder joint somewhere on the board. While such problems can often be fixed by a heat gun I would not recommend it to a novice. Even an expert would first have to locate the bad joint (probably on the controller chip, but could be elsewhere) and there would still be the risk of causing more damage. Maybe better cooling (especially of the controller/south bridge) can work around your problem, but I would not rely on that either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, looking at what you've done so far, we can rule out that its the drive. There's two possible places issues can happen here. Firstly, the IDE port on the motherboard - but thats not likely, and a pain to fix. The other could be that the IDE cable itself has broken down over time - you may want to try swapping the cable to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with your last assessment, sounds to me like its the IDE port on the motherboard that's broken down somehow. I'd suggest confirming this by connecting something else (maybe a HDD?) to that same port and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a CD? There are two competing DVD standards, and older drives can only read one of them. (DVD+R or DVD-R)

Comment: The disc is a Philips DVD+RW. My drive is a LG GH22NP20BB that support +/- R, RW, RAM, DL, R9. I don't think it's an older drive.

Comment: Try an R disk; +/-RW might be different yet.

Comment: I also tried with a CD-R, it didn't worked.

Comment: What is odd is that my driver can't read any disc. I tried with driver disc from a product and a windows game and I've got error too (I updated my question)

Comment: Sounds like a dirty lens. Try a cleaning CD.